# Angular Material Filter Table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to add a Filter option for my Material Table in Angular, but I am getting these two errors, which specify on 'value':

```
Object is possibly 'null'.
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

Here is my .html file:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" matInput placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
```

And the .ts file:

```
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

What am I doing wrong/ What should I be doing different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1:

Add `id` (#filter) to input and retrieve value with `filter.value`

```
<input matInput #filter (keyup)="applyFilter(filter.value)" placeholder="Filter">
```

---

### Solution 2:

Add another function to handle event and parse value to `applyFilter`.

> .component.ts

```
fireFilterEvent(event: Event) {
  const input = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  this.applyFilter(input);
}
```

For your `input` element, you call `fireFilterEvent($event)` on `(keyup)` event.

> .component.html

```
<input matInput (keyup)="fireFilterEvent($event)" placeholder="Filter">
```

Comment: You are welcome, good to see that my answer can help you.