# Angular 12.1 doesn't work "$event.target.value"

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular, and I'm learning angular via youtube, which has one example, and I'm getting an error on that example, and my code is attached below, help me out.

**HTML**

`<input type="text" (keyup)="getVal($event.target.value)">`

**TypeScript**

```
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'test';
    getVal(val: any)
  {
    console.log(val);
  };
};
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: This is expected behaviour. `$event.target` can be `null` and it can lead to runtime errors if you try to directly access a property of it.

Comment: @JSONDerulo `<input type="text" (keyup)="getVal(($event)?.target.value)">`I still got an Error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68289665/angular-typescript-event-target-value/68289722#68289722

Comment: @Chellappanவ typecasting to `any` works but is not a good solution. As I mentioned, it can lead to runtime errors.

Comment: @JSONDerulo as mentioned in the documentation When using $event.target for DOM events (because of the possibility of event bubbling, $event.target in the DOM typings doesn't have the type you might expect). In that case we need to use $any casting to avoid type error:https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#troubleshooting-template-errors

Comment: Alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68269259/8017690

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
getVal(event: KeyboardEvent) {

    if ((event.target as HTMLInputElement)?.value) {
      // do stuff
    }
}
```

and pass in the event:

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="getVal($event)">
```

Comment: No sir still got an Error.